# Inline calls to virtual methods inside a final class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, polymorphism, inline

Suppose I have a `class A` that is a **final** heir.

I have a public virtual method `foo()`.

I have a private method `bar()` that wants to re-use `foo()` without extra overhead on a virtual call. How can I inline the call?

If I make `foo()`'s definition `inline`, the non-virtual thunk is not generated anymore and I get `" undefined reference to non-virtual thunk to... "` link error.

The only way that I know is to have a private non-virtual `inline` method `foo_()`. Then I may have:

```cpp
virtual void A::foo() { foo_(); } 

virtual void A::bar() { foo_(); // now do bar's staff }

inline void foo_() { // thing to do } // note inline
```

But this is ugly. Is there a better way? Or maybe what I want is something wrong? But as the `class A` is final, I think it is okay.

**UPDATE:** I made a further investigation on the problem and posted its result as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313452/4781940).

Comment: `virtual void A::bar() { A::foo(); }`?

Comment: I tried this also, but it did not help. I checked with `objdump`. Thank you!

Comment: if class (or method) is `final`, then compiler might do devirtualization...

Comment: Yes, but it does not. I compile with `-O2`. Gcc 11.2. x64.

Comment: Just I thought it's something quite regular -- what many programmers would want to improve the performance. And I cannot get it.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe mark the method itself `final` as well?

Comment: @chuck I have just checked. Alas, it did not help also. Thank you!

Comment: `virtual void A::foo()` makes no sense if `A` is final. Did you mean `void A::foo() override` ?

Comment: From assembly, `A::foo();` avoid virtual overhead [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/addYThjGn).

Comment: @Jarod42, I want the call to be inlined actually not just to eliminate a virtual call.

Comment: It is inlined [here](https://godbolt.org/z/enPdhYd4s).

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree: https://godbolt.org/z/o1Tchbx7G . However, for my project it does not work. Maybe, it's due to the fact that my final heir is inherited from QDialog and the abstract class at once. So sad.

Comment: And it's also strange that I get this " undefined reference to non-virtual thunk to... " error when trying to make the function inline. While in the simple example I don't get the error. Will update on my further investigation that I am going to make tomorrow.

Comment: @Jarod42 I investigated the problem further and posted the result as an answer. Could you, please, be so kind to glance. I am not sure maybe I will post the "answer" as a new question, so that more people would notice it.

Comment: @Jarod42 I deleted the "answer" from here and posted it as a new separate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313452/4781940 .